# Error: java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed

Tags: hazelcast

Can anyone help me with following error.When it will happen.What is the effect.I don't have knowledge on hazelcast.
remoteEndpoint=Address, Error: java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's a warning message that gets logged whenever a client loses the connection to the cluster for various reasons(client shutdown/network issue/firewall etc.)

Comment: Thanks for reply that helps me a lot.

Comment: If network issue resolves after some time ,client will regain the connection to the cluster automatically or do we need to restart client.?

Comment: @sravs you can configure the number of connection attempts and the period between reconnection attempts in the Java client with `<connection-attempt-limit>` and `<connection-attempt-period>` in declarative configuration (or the equivalent in programmatic configuration). See section "Configuring Client Network" under http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-client-network for more.